# Raisepropertychanged is null and does not notify the property after datacontext changed

Tags: uwp, uno-platform, winui

I have a mainPage in which I am calling my user control. The idea is that I have a `TextBlock`, and upon click of a button I am changing the Text which is above the Hello World name.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello, world!" Margin="20" FontSize="30" />
        <local1:GenericControl></local1:GenericControl>

        <Button x:Name="create" Click="clickBtn"/>
    </Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public TestViewModel viewModel { get; set; } = new TestViewModel();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
        }

        public void clickBtn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

            var m = ((Button)sender).DataContext as TestViewModel;
            m.CreateModel.HeaderText = "tripathi";
            viewModel = m;
            var s = new GenericControl {
                
                DataContext = viewModel
            };
        }

    }
```

and below is the user control what I am creating from code behind:

```
public GenericControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            //this.DataContext = this;
            DataContextChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                var createModel = this.DataContext as TestViewModel;
                CreateControl(createModel.CreateModel);
            };
        }

        private void CreateControl(Test t) {
            var grid = new Grid();
            grid.SetBinding(Grid.DataContextProperty, new Binding { Source = DataContext, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
            //grid.DataContext = this.DataContext;
            var tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding { Source = t.HeaderText, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
                 , UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged});

            grid.Children.Add(tb);
            gridlayout.Children.Add(grid);
        }
```

GenericControl.xaml:

```
<Grid Name="gridlayout">

    </Grid>
```

TestViewModel:

```
private Test _createModel = new Test();

        private string _textHeader;

        public Test CreateModel
        {
            get { return _createModel; }
            set { _createModel = value;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                RaisePropertyChanged("CreateModel");

                });
            }
        }

        public TestViewModel() {
            CreateModel.HeaderText = "Ankit";
            CreateModel = CreateModel;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
```

Model:

```
private string _headerText;

        public string HeaderText
        {
            get { return _headerText; }
            set { _headerText = value;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);
                    RaisePropertyChanged("HeaderText");

                });

            }
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "") {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
```

I am getting correct values on debugging, but it is not showing in UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue here for the binding not working is that you should not set the `Source` property of the binding here:

```cs
tb.SetBinding(
  TextBlock.TextProperty, 
  new Binding { 
    Source = t.HeaderText, 
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
  });
```

As doing so is basically saying to the Binding engine to observe the string instance that is in `t.HeaderText` at the creation of the binding, which is most likely null, and cannot change as it `string` is not observable.

What you'll want is to do the following instead:

```cs
tb.SetBinding(
  TextBlock.TextProperty,
  new Binding { 
    Path = new PropertyPath("CreateModel.HeaderText"), 
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
  });
```

This will instruct the binding engine to se the current `DataContext` when the `TextBlock` is added into `gridLayout`, which is of type `TestViewModel`.

You also do not need this line:

```cs
grid.SetBinding(
  Grid.DataContextProperty, 
  new Binding { 
    Source = DataContext, 
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay 
  });
```

As this is done automatically by the framework.

You should also be careful about creating UI on the DataContext changed and not clearing it, where:

```cs
gridlayout.Children.Add(grid);
```

will continuously add `TextBlock` instances to the `gridLayout`, without removing previous ones.

And finally, you should not raise event changes this way:

```cs
set { 
    _createModel = value;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        RaisePropertyChanged("CreateModel");

    });
}
```

as you'll raise from a non-UI thread, and will cause an exception. Make sure to use [`Dispatcher.RunAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync?view=winrt-18362) instead.

Comment: Thanks Jerome Laban. I am creating dynamic page from code behind but my problem is binding expression as we gave above in the control is not working in wasm..It showing a blank page if i use the binding expression on the textblock or any control.

Comment: If it's not working only on Wasm, it could be a linker issue, where your viewmodel or model is in another assembly. You'll have to add it to the LinkerConfig.xml file.